# Closure of $BC_\gamma$ in $BC_0$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $BC_0=C_0([0,\infty);\mathbb R)$, the space of continuous functions on $[0,\infty)$ vanishing at infinity with sup norm, and $BC_\gamma=\{f\in BC_0: t^\gamma|f(t)|=O(1)\text{ as }t\to\infty\}$ with $\gamma>0$. I wonder if the closure of $BC_\gamma$ in $BC_0$ is a properly subspace of $BC_0$ or not. If yes, how to describe this subspace? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, $BC_0$ is the closure of a *smaller* space: the functions with compact support. Take a sequence of bump functions $\psi_n$ s.t.
$$0\le\psi_n\le 1,$$
$$\psi_n(x)=1 \text{ for } x\in[0,n],$$
$$\psi_n(x)=0 \text{ for } x\in[n+1,\infty).$$
Then for any $f\in BC_0$, $\psi_nf\to f$ in the $\sup$ norm because...

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very good counterexample